# How to select items which sells increased compared to historical average

Tags: mysql, aggregate, average

I want to obtain a seasonal view from my sold items, so I could know which products will sell more next month (for instance). I want it to be compared to the average sales of this product

The query, in "human words", would be something like this:

> What are the produts which sales [next month, last year¹] increased
>   compared to the historical avergage sales for this product

OR

> What are the products which sales at april/2016 were bigger than the
>   product's historical average sales

What I'm wanting to do is to discover which itens will sell more next month, so I can know how much of it I should buy.

My approach was to create a view containing the total sales and average sales, then making a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    s.ITEM_ID,
    v.NAME,
    SUM(s.SOLD_PRICE) AS TOTAL,
    v.AVERAGE AS AVG_SALE
FROM 
    sales s
JOIN    
    view_averages v
ON
    s.ITEM_ID = v.ITEM_ID
WHERE 
    MONTH(s.SALE_DATE) = 3 AND YEAR(s.SALE_DATE)= 2016 AND
    TOTAL > AVG_SALE
GROUP BY
    s.ITEM_ID
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

But I`m not quite sure if it is the best method.

I`d appreciate any inputs, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the following query

```
SELECT 
    a.ITEM_ID, 
    a.NAME, 
    AVG(a.TOTAL_SALE) AVG_SALE, 
    SUM(IF(a.`year` = 2016 AND a.`month` = 3, a.TOTAL_SALE, 0)) AS TOTAL
FROM (
    SELECT 
    s.ITEM_ID,
    s.NAME,
    YEAR(s.SALE_DATE) `year`,
    MONTH(s.SALE_DATE) `month`,
    SUM(s.SOLD_PRICE) AS TOTAL_SALE
FROM 
    sales s
GROUP BY
    s.ITEM_ID,s.NAME, YEAR(s.SALE_DATE), MONTH(s.SALE_DATE)
) a
GROUP BY a.ITEM_ID
HAVING TOTAL > AVG_SALE
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

With this query it only uses the sales table once where the inner query aggregates monthly information about sales. The outer query then averages all monthly sales sums, and only keeps the ones that has MONTHLY SALE SUM FOR specific month > AVG SALE SUM

One more thing to maybe think about, is if you want only the historic sales average preceding the month, or if you want the historic sales averages for the entire time you have data for.
The query I made takes averages for the entire time you have data for

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I want the query to consider the entire time before "next month", so you're right.
But I noticed one mistake (my mistake): I have to find the monthly average sale, so I can compare months' sales. When I ask the average for the whole period of time, I'd get the historical average, so it isn't suitable to compare to month's average. 
But I think that I could tweak your query to achieve that.
I'll try to do that and make some tests, as I do know, by another means, some products which sales will increase in march.